# Radgrid get cell value when in edit mode

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a radgrid and a textbox where I would like to show the value of a column when the record is in edit mode. The value I would like to get is contained in a readonly column and it is listed in DataKeyNames, it is basically the transaction id given by the SQL database when the item is created.

```
<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TransazioneID" AllowFilteringByColumn="True">
```

I cannot get it out.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {

        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
           string str = item["TransazioneID"].Text;
           TextBox1.Text = str;
```

The code doesn't give me errors but shows nothing. How can I get the value of "TransactionID" for the record in edit mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code to get the datakey value in edit mode.

```
protected void rdg_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            string str = editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("TransazioneID").ToString();
            TextBox1.Text = str ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ,

```
      GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
      int tID = Int32.Parse(editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["TransazioneID"].ToString());
```